# cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.razorpay.com:443

Tags: curl, razorpay

I have integrated 'razorpay' payment gateway for my application. **Initially it has worked fine but after the site moved to 'godaddy' server getting the issue** while checkout. Error is related to cURL and razorpay api. below is the error:

```
Error : cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.razorpay.com:443
```

checkout.php

```
use Razorpay\Api\Api;
$api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);
--------
--------
$orderData = [
    'receipt'         => 1,
    'amount'          => $order_paise, // 2000 rupees in paise
    'currency'        => 'INR',
    'payment_capture' => 1 // auto capture
];
try{
    $razorpayOrder = $api->order->create($orderData);   
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error : ' . $e->getMessage();exit;
}
```

Where is the issue coming, in the code or in api or server. Whats wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a problem in the ssl handshake. Not sure if this could help but you can check which are the cipher suites accepted by api.razorpay.com:443 and see if godaddy has any in common. If yes perhaps you can set the suite in the curl options. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you please tell how to check that?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a same problem after moving to Godaddy but upgrading php version from 5.4 to 5.6 solve my problem.
Try this, it really works!